# PHP imagegrabwindow:: Getting a blank image back. Why?

Tags: php, xampp, screenshot, capture, server

I'm using that script to capture a screenshot.

```
$Browser = new COM('InternetExplorer.Application');
$Browserhandle = $Browser->HWND;
$Browser->Visible = true;
$Browser->Fullscreen = true;
$Browser->Navigate('http://www.stackoverflow.com');

while($Browser->Busy){
    com_message_pump(4000);
}

$img = imagegrabwindow($Browserhandle, 0);
$Browser->Quit();
imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');
```

Yes, screenshot.png IS exists after running that script but it's completely blank.

I'm using XAMPP server PHP version 5.4.4

Comment: error reporting? are you on windows? installed the gd image library if not presents?

Comment: some comments here may be useful about activating some function of apache: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php

Comment: Yes, That was the problem! I was needed to activate the interaction with the desktop BUT it looks like it saves the page before it fully loaded so I'm getting half picture and moreover, How do I capture all of the page (means capture all INCLUDE all assume that page scrolled down until the end of the page) ?

Comment: i think you can open another question for that, i do not know, sorry about that